# Copy specific columns from one sheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy certain columns like A, B, H from one sheet to another and I copied this code to a module but I got a "run time error 9".

```
Sub CopyColumnToWorkbook()
Dim sourceColumn As Range, targetColumn As Range

Set sourceColumn = Workbooks("sheet1.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns("A")
Set targetColumn = Workbooks("sheet2.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns("A")

sourceColumn.Copy Destination:=targetColumn
End
```

I am working on data which has 55 columns and 453 rows. How could I copy alternate columns from one worksheet to another...example

I want only columns of 2010-2011 year. In my data..year 2010-2011 and year 2011-2012 are arranged in alternate basis like one column for April 2010-2011 and next column for April 2011-2012..again next column is for may 2010-2011 and next is may -2011-2012..and so on.

Comment: Both workbooks "sheet1.xlsm" and "sheet2.xlsm" must be open before running that code. The "run time error 9" is `Subscript out of Range`. That means: there is not such item in the collection. I suspect: there is not "sheet1.xlsm" or "sheet2.xlsm"  in the `Workbooks` collection.

Comment: Your question implies you are copying data between different sheets in 1 workbook, but your code tries to copy between workbooks (files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a like statement, for example:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
    Dim col As Long, rng As Range, c As Range, cRng As Range, cRws As Long, col2 As Long

    Set sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set sh2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

    With sh1
        col = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, col))

        For Each c In rng.Cells

            If c Like "*2010-2011*" Then
                cRws = .Cells(.Rows.Count, c.Column).End(xlUp).Row
                Set cRng = .Range(.Cells(1, c.Column), .Cells(cRws, c.Column))

                cRng.Copy sh2.Cells(1, sh2.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1)
            End If

        Next c
    End With

    sh2.Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    sh2.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

End Sub
```